# Why isn't a final variable always a constant expression?

Tags: java, expression, constants, compile-time-constant, narrowing

In the below code:

```
final int a;
a=2;
byte b=a;   // error: possible loss of precision
```

Why do I get this error? Isn't `a` final variable compile time constant expression and hence implicitly narrowed to byte during the assignment?

In other words isn't the above code equivalent to:

```
final int a=2;
byte b=a;
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The compiler isn't that smart.

*We* can tell that the value will always be 2. But what if we had something like this?

```
class ABC{
    final int a;

    public ABC(){
       if(Math.random() < .5){
          a = 2;
       }
       else{
          a = 12345;
       }

       byte b = a;
    }
}
```

The compiler is not smart enough to tell these two cases apart, so it gives you an error instead.

Comment: In fact the compiler isn't allowed to be that smart.

Comment: @usr That's some serious primitive religion there. Seriously: Why is that? Compilers are sensitive to numbers `1`, `2`, `4`, and etc when multiplying. The case in this answer is clearly unsolvable, because the values returned from `random` depends on the time the program starts.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky But even if the computation were deterministic and the compiler could figure it out, it still would not be allowed to treat it as a constant expression (removing the need for the cast). It's important that what is or isn't a valid java program doesn't depend on how smart a particular compiler is.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You are just saying that compilers should stick to the standard. Good point.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky Pretty much. In C++ it's common for compilers to add their own extensions. In Java, it's basically forbidden (see the Microsoft lawsuit).

Answer (score 51):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A *blank `final`* is a `final` variable whose declaration lacks an initializer.
>
> A constant variable is a `final` variable of primitive type or type
>   `String` that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28).

Your variable

```
final int a;
```

is a *blank `final`* variable. It lacks an initializer. The second paragraph doesn't apply to it because it is not initialized at declaration. It therefore isn't a constant expression.

This applies to fields as well.

Answer (score 2):

As final variables can be delayed initialized and the compiler cannot determine for b that it has a value in the case branch.